# adding framework to Xcode 7

Tags: frameworks, xcode7

I'm unable to find and add `AVFoundation` framework and other framework like Xcode6 we were able to do on Xcode 7 beta
is there any way to add `AVFoundation` to the project?

Answer (score 1):

Apple added a new feature called [module](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/Modules.html) which is semantic to import. It's kind of a better implementation of the pre-compiled headers.

Modules are a packaging together of the framework executable and it's headers.

One of the big advantages of using `@import` is that you don't need to add the framework in the project settings, it's done automatically.

Add any framework like below,

[image]

Please let me know if you need anymore clarification on this.